# Dockerfile 'RUN git clone' removes intermediate container

Tags: git, docker, boot2docker, git-clone

I using Boot2Docker on Windows 7 to build my developement environment with a Dockerfile. When i run `docker build -t myimage dir/of/docker/file`, then everything works fine until this line:

```
RUN git clone --verbose https://github.com/zsh-users/antigen ~/.antigen/antigen
```

The output of this line is:

```
Step 12 : RUN git clone --verbose https://github.com/zsh-users/antigen ~/.antigen/antigen
---> Running in 26cba91e912a
Cloning into '/root/.antigen/antigen'...
POST git-upload-pack (302 bytes)
---> e0012659884b
Removing intermediate container 26cba91e912a
Successfully built e0012659884b
```

The clone (of a public repository) is droped, the ~/.antigen/antigen isn't exists in the container.
The "Cloning into..." is red, so i think there is something wrong with the command. But if i'm running it in the container's shell (opened by `docker run -it myimage`) it clones it.

Am i doing something wrong, or may i do some setup to use `git clone` in dockerfile? Here's the full content of it:

```
FROM debian:testing
MAINTAINER BimbaLaszlo

RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get install -y curl

RUN apt-get install -y gcc g++ make
RUN apt-get install -y ctags
RUN apt-get install -y git

RUN apt-get install -y python python-pip python3 python3-pip

RUN apt-get install -y ruby ruby-dev
RUN gem install ripper-tags gem-ripper-tags
RUN gem install pry byebug

RUN apt-get install -y zsh
RUN git clone --progress --verbose https://github.com/zsh-users/antigen ~/.antigen/antigen
```

Comment: I just built and ran your Dockerfile and can verify that it worked properly. The steps I did: 
1. Created `Dockerfile` with your content.
2. `docker build -t test1 .`
3. `docker run -it test1 /bin/bash`    Then, inside container: 
`root@4a087cf0fece:~# ls .antigen/antigen`
Can see all your files cloned.

Comment: Did you run it on Linux or Windows?

Comment: I did it in OS X, with boot2docker. Should be same with Windows as well.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, repo from git clone disappears from image, not sure why, I'm under Linux.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The color you see in red, is not caused by error. It's because `git clone` doesn't use `STDOUT`, we can verity it by following command:

```
$ git clone --progress --verbose https://github.com/zsh-users/antigen > /dev/null
Cloning into 'antigen'...
POST git-upload-pack (255 bytes)
remote: Counting objects: 1291, done.
remote: Total 1291 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 1291
Receiving objects: 100% (1291/1291), 1.10 MiB | 900.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (688/688), done.
Checking connectivity... done.

$ git clone --progress --verbose https://github.com/zsh-users/antigen 2&> /dev/null
```

In the first command, I redirected all `STDOUT` into `/dev/null`, we can still see the output. But in the second command, I redirected all `STDERR` into `/dev/null`, so we saw nothing.

And in `docker build`, if any output is not in `STDOUT`, it will turn RED. That's it.

So nothing is wrong with your Dockerfile.

Comment: If everything is OK, then why "Removing intermediate container 26cba91e912a"?

Comment: Docker run always removes containers it used for building images.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're cloning not cloning into a path declared as `VOLUME` by your base image.

Because:

> If any build steps change the data within the volume after it has been declared, those changes will be discarded.

according to: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#notes-about-specifying-volumes

If you don't have access to the Dockerfile, you can inspect the image:

```
sudo docker inspect alpine/git | jq ".[0].Config.Volumes"
```

Change your `WORKDIR` to e.g. `/root` to retain the files:

```
# base image declares WORKDIR /git also as VOLUME
FROM alpine/git 
WORKDIR /root
RUN git clone --verbose https://github.com/zsh-users/antigen ~/.antigen/antigen
ENTRYPOINT /bin/sh
```